# Mean Log10-Linear regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, log-linear

In field experiment I have gathered data for X and Y with the aim to fit a regression and use X to predict Y in the future. Based on physics, I know the relationship should be of the form
$y = 10^{a \cdot x + b}$. I have used a log10 - linear model $log_{10}(y_i) = a x_i + b + \epsilon_i$ to fit $a$ and $b$ using least squares. The values of $x_i$ were controlled for.

I have a second data set $x_j, j=1,...,n$ which is not controlled for but assumed to be a representative sample. I am using the model to predict $y_j$. My $y_j$ go into a complex numerical model which returns $z_j = f(y_j)$, where $f$ represents the model.

I am interested in finding $\mu_Z$ and its 95% confidence interval. How would I do that?

My initial idea was to bootstrap residuals and propagating them through the regression and the numerical model. However, I realized that if I take the mean of my bootstrapped values for Z, it is not the same as when taking the mean of all $log(y_j)$ and propagating that through the model. How can I determine $\mu_Z$?

Comment: Welcome to the site! First, what is the relation between $x_i$ and $x_j$, i.e. what does the first paragraph have to do with the second? What are controlled vs not controlled variables (in regression, control variables are extra regressors used to avoid omitted variables bias)? Lastly, indeed it generally holds that $E[f(x)] \ne f(E[x])$ for any $x$, with some exceptions. Since you want the mean of $f(\cdot)$, and *not* the $f(\cdot)$ of the mean, I think it's straight-forward that you should calculate the mean of all $z_j$, that is the mean of all $f(y_j)$, just like you did.

Comment: 1) I cannot use the first data set to determine the distribution of Y, as the way I selected x and y was not random. In the second data set x is randomly selected. 
2) I am still confused: In a linear regression 
$y_i = ax_i + b + \epsilon_i$ the value $y_i* = ax_i +b$ can be interpreted as a conditional mean of y given x_i. This interpretation changes for $y_i* = 10^{ax_i + b}$ where a and b have be quantified using $log_{10}(y_i) = ax_i + b + \epsilon_i$. This makes me think that it is not straight-forward to use a log-linear regression for prediction, if one is not interested in the log

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your question. I thought that by "predicting $y$" you implied taking the log to the power 10. You predict $\widehat{log_{10}(y)}$ and then simply take the result to the power 10 to get the true scale: $\hat{y}=10^{\widehat{log_{10}(y)}}$. That's your typical log-transform procedure with regression. Was this your question?

Comment: I think my question is not very clear yet. I am trying myself to pin-point the issue. New attempt: If I were to bootstrap the (normally distributed for simplicity) residuals I would find a symmetric confidence interval around $\hat{log10(y)}$, but I would find a shifted interval for $\hat(y)$.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://web.vu.lt/mif/a.buteikis/wp-content/uploads/PE_Book/3-7-UnivarPredict.html There is a difference between the prediction and the corrected prediction.

Comment: This is also a useful link https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10691898.2005.11910638

Comment: Thanks for sharing! and sorry for not getting back to you in time, I am caught up in something at the moment. But if you found the answer please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (once you get enough reputation) and/or editing your question.